# iBooks Store: How do I know what format is used?

Tags: books, itunes-store, ebook

I see a technical book on the iBooks store which looks interesting. The description tells me everything except:

- What format (PDF, ePub etc) is supplied?
- Does the book have DRM?

I don’t know whether the answer is always the same, but how can I find out about the book on the store?

Comment: One publisher that does not use DRM is O'Reilly.  Otherwise I would assume paid books do have it.

Comment: @TomGewecke I used to buy books directly from O’Reilly, and one of the benefits was, as you say, no DRM. However, they’ve stopped selling them. When I emailed them about where to buy books, and whether they would still be DRM free, the reply was vague.

Answer (score 1):

Books from the iBooks Store are always in the .ibooks or .epub format. It is never PDF.

Books from the iBooks Store can be DRM-protected, but they don't have to be. It is up to the publisher of the book to decide.

To check for DRM you can select the book and choose "Get Info" from the Files menu. If this shows "Purchased book" it is non-DRM, if it shows "Protected book" it is DRM-protected.

Comment: The DRM check only works after purchase/download of the book, right?

Comment: What do you mean “only works”?

Comment: @tomgewecke Do you have a source on ePub from the iBooks Store? As far as I know this is not the case.

Comment: Well, to do „Get Info“ you need to download the book first. It‘s not possible to check DRM protection *before* the purchase this way. But good to know for purchased books.

Comment: @jksoegaard See the first part of.  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201183

Comment: But aren’t the ePub files converted to .ibooks by Apple during the publishing process so that the customer always downloads .ibooks files?

Comment: @jksoegaard No, there is no conversion.  You can see the .epub in the file names on your computer.  I think all novels are probably epub.